# Rate of convergence of an iterative scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have the iterative scheme $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2}(1+\frac{a}{x_n})=0$. It converges to $√a$. I have to find the rate of convergence of this scheme.

I tried to find a form like $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ but couldn't.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference equation$$x_{n+1}-\frac12 x_n=\frac a2$$ has a closed form solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some typo, because $\sqrt{a}$ is in general not a fixed point in this case; for example when $a=4$ plugging in $x_n=2$ gives $x_{n+1}=3$.

Comment: @Ian I wrote the equations and values exactly as they were given in my lecture notes... Now there might be some typo in there which I don't know about.

Comment: @Mark Viola oh! Can you please guide me to some resource where I can see more about it?

Comment: If you want to follow Mark's suggestion, you can look up "linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients". But it won't help with the typo, and actually the problem that I think you are probably expected to solve is not of this class. That problem is $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} \left ( x_n + \frac{a}{x_n} \right )$.

Comment: @Ian okay. Thanks, I think I'll look into it then...

Comment: Your sequence actually is $x_{n+1}={x_n+a\over 2}$ which tends to $a$. Is the question stated correctly?

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz yes I have checked it again. It is the one given in my notes. But I see now in my book that from Newton-Raphson's formula, they have deduced something similar to this to find the solution for $x=√N$. I think this might be a misrepresentation of that formula (I'm not sure though).

Comment: In this case, we have ${x_{n+1}-a\over x_n-a}={1\over 2}$ and the convergence rate is $1$.